# How do I create a method with a dict of fuel types and corresponding default unit prices integer values and make them appear in a form in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo

How do I make it possible when the user selects the **Fuel Type** in the form , the **Unit Price** will automatically display the integer unit value for corresponding fuel type chosen. For example when user selects `petroleum` the value of `0.87`*(currency is in dollars)* should appear automatically at unit price field.

Here is the code for the class I created for the station registration

```
# Fuel Station register Class
class fleet_fuel_stn_reg(osv.Model):
    _name = 'fleet.fuel.station.reg'
    _description = 'Contains fuel station details to register'

    _columns = {
        'station':fields.char('Station Name'),
        # 'partner':fields.many2one('fleet.partner','Partner', required=True),
        'location':fields.char('Location',  help='Location of the vehicle (garage, ...'),
        'fuel_type': fields.selection([('petroleum', 'Petroleum'), ('diesel', 'Diesel'), ('kerosene', 'Kerosene')], 'Fuel Type', help='Fuel Used by the vehicle'),
        'stocklevel':fields.float('Stock Level'),
        'unit':fields.selection([('litres', 'Litres')], 'Odometer Unit', help='Unit of the odometer ',required=True),
        'unit_price':fields.float('Unit Price'),
        'init_stock':fields.float('Initial Stock'),
        'init_stock_taken':fields.date('Initial Stock Taken In'),
    }
```

#### Here is how the interface looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the version 8 of Odoo or later (because of your question tags), so first of all, if you're creating a new model, like in this case, you should use new API, it will be much easier for you. So let's move your code from old API to new API, and what you're looking for will be done by the `onchange` method:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

# Fuel Station register Class
class FleetFuelStnReg(models.Model):
    _name = 'fleet.fuel.station.reg'
    _description = 'Contains fuel station details to register'

    station = fields.Char(
        string='Station Name',
    )
    location = fields.Char(
        string='Location', 
        help='Location of the vehicle (garage, ...)',
    )
    fuel_type = fields.Selection(
        selection=[
            ('petroleum', 'Petroleum'),
            ('diesel', 'Diesel'),
            ('kerosene', 'Kerosene'),
        ],
        string='Fuel Type',
        help='Fuel Used by the vehicle',
    )
    stocklevel = fields.Float(
        string='Stock Level',
    )
    unit = fields.Selection(
        selection=[
            ('litres', 'Litres'),
        ],
        string='Odometer Unit',
        help='Unit of the odometer',
        required=True,
    )
    unit_price: fields.Float(
        string='Unit Price'
    )
    init_stock: fields.Float(
        string='Initial Stock'
    )
    init_stock_taken = fields.Date(
        string='Initial Stock Taken In',
    )

@api.onchange('fuel_type')
def onchange_fuel_type(self):
    if self.fuel_type == 'petroleum':
        self.unit_price = 0.87
    elif self.fuel_type == 'diesel':
        self.unit_price = 0.70
    else:
        self.unit_price = 0.99
```

**EDIT**

As you commented me that fuel types haven't fixed values, the field can't be a `Selection` one. You must use a `Many2one` field, which implies that you must create a class for fuel types first:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class FuelType(models.Model):
    _name = 'fuel.type'
    _description = 'All the available fuel types'

    name = fields.Char(
        string='Name',
        required=True,
    )
    price_unit = fields.Float(
        string='Unit price',
        required=True,
    ) 

# Fuel Station register Class
class FleetFuelStnReg(models.Model):
    _name = 'fleet.fuel.station.reg'
    _description = 'Contains fuel station details to register'

    station = fields.Char(
        string='Station Name',
    )
    location = fields.Char(
        string='Location', 
        help='Location of the vehicle (garage, ...)',
    )
    fuel_type = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='fuel.type',
        string='Fuel Type',
        help='Fuel Used by the vehicle',
    )
    stocklevel = fields.Float(
        string='Stock Level',
    )
    unit = fields.Selection(
        selection=[
            ('litres', 'Litres'),
        ],
        string='Odometer Unit',
        help='Unit of the odometer',
        required=True,
    )
    unit_price: fields.Float(
        string='Unit Price'
    )
    init_stock: fields.Float(
        string='Initial Stock'
    )
    init_stock_taken = fields.Date(
        string='Initial Stock Taken In',
    )

@api.onchange('fuel_type')
def onchange_fuel_type(self):
    self.unit_price = self.fuel_type.price_unit
```

Comment: Thanks forvas, you know that the fuel  values will keep on changing depending on the fuel markets we could also make the values easy to edit rather than hard  codng.

Comment: Of course, in that case `fuel_type` must be a `Many2one` field instead of a `Selection` one. In the XML view you could write `<field name="fuel_type" widget="selection"/>` to avoid users creating new fuel types. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @philip did this answer help you? If so, validate it to set it as closed